# zone.js:672 Uncaught (in promise) Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:4200/angular2/platform/browser

Tags: angular

When i am loading my angular app to local host the following error occur and nothing is display.

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading 
http://localhost:4200/angular2/platform/browser
Error loading http://localhost:4200/angular2/platform/browser
at o (system.src.js:4597) [<root>]
at XMLHttpRequest.I.s.onreadystatechange (system.src.js:4597) [<root>]
```

Dependency:

```
"@angular/animations": "^5.2.7",
"@angular/cdk": "^5.2.3",
"@angular/common": "^5.2.7",
"@angular/compiler": "^5.2.7",
"@angular/core": "^5.2.7",
"@angular/forms": "^5.2.7",
"@angular/http": "^5.2.7-rc.1",
"@angular/material": "^5.2.3",
"@angular/platform-browser": "^5.2.7",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.2.7",
"@angular/platform-server": "^5.2.7",
"@angular/router": "^5.2.7",
"@angular/upgrade": "2.4.9",
"angular-2-data-table": "^0.1.2",
"angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc.5-next",
"bootstrap": "^4.0.0",
"chart.js": "2.5.0",
"core-js": "2.4.1",
"firebase": "^4.10.1",
"moment": "2.17.1",
"ng2-bootstrap": "1.4.0",
"ng2-charts": "1.5.0",
"ngx-toastr": "^8.2.1",
"promise-polyfill": "7.1.0",
"rxjs": "^5.5.6",
"ts-helpers": "1.1.2",
"zone.js": "0.7.2"
```

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ApplicationRef, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HashLocationStrategy, LocationStrategy } from '@angular/common';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
 import { FormsModule, NgForm, NgModel, ReactiveFormsModule } from 
'@angular/forms';
import { DropdownModule } from 'ng2-bootstrap/dropdown';
import { TabsModule } from 'ng2-bootstrap/tabs';
import { ChartsModule } from 'ng2-charts/ng2-charts';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import { SignupComponent } from './auth/signup/signup.component';
import { SigninComponent } from './auth/signin/signin.component';

import { NAV_DROPDOWN_DIRECTIVES } from './shared/nav-dropdown.directive';
import { SIDEBAR_TOGGLE_DIRECTIVES } from './shared/sidebar.directive';
import { AsideToggleDirective } from './shared/aside.directive';
import { BreadcrumbsComponent } from './shared/breadcrumb.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app.routing';
import { FullLayoutComponent } from './layouts/full-layout.component';
import { SimpleLayoutComponent } from './layouts/simple-layout.component';
import { AuthService } from './auth/auth.service';
import { ActivitiesComponent } from './activities/activities.component';

@NgModule({

declarations: [
//    RegisterComponent,
AppComponent,

FullLayoutComponent,
SimpleLayoutComponent,
NAV_DROPDOWN_DIRECTIVES,
BreadcrumbsComponent,
SIDEBAR_TOGGLE_DIRECTIVES,
AsideToggleDirective,
SignupComponent,
SigninComponent,
ActivitiesComponent

 ],
 imports: [
BrowserModule,
AppRoutingModule,
DropdownModule.forRoot(),
TabsModule.forRoot(),
ChartsModule,
CommonModule,
FormsModule,
ReactiveFormsModule,
HttpModule,
],

providers: [AuthService,{
provide: LocationStrategy,
useClass: HashLocationStrategy
}],
bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

There is no error in the command prompt, but when the app is loaded into the localhost the error occur in the console.I dont know what is the problem. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: did you check if there is actually an angular2 folder under node_modules?

Comment: there are 2 folders one is angular and other is angularfire2. I updated this app from angular 2 to 5.